# Output Stylus files to custom directory in express3

Tags: node.js, express, stylus

I have my project and was porting some code over from express2.5.7 to express3.0.3. I thought it was almost be a 1:1 transfer, but I'm running into an issue of not being able to compile my stylus files into the directory I specified.  Here is my basic app.js setup:

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , nib = require('nib')
  , bootstrap = require('bootstrap-stylus')
  , stylus = require('stylus');

var app = module.exports = express();

app.configure('dev', function(){
  var stylusMiddleware = stylus.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/stylus/', // .styl files are located in `/stylus`
    dest: __dirname + '/public/css/', // .styl resources are compiled `/css/*.css`
    debug: true,
    compile: function(str, path) { // optional, but recommended
      console.log(path);
      return stylus(str)
        .set('filename', path)
        //.set('warn', true)
        .set('compress', true)
        .use(bootstrap())
    }
  });
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(stylusMiddleware);  
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); 
  app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
});

app.configure('prod', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

I've tested the `app.configure` stuff and it is going through the correct methods ('dev' and the configure with just a function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I try to set up custom `src` and `dest` too and I can't. In search of solutions I looked into the Stylus source. In two words pathes to `styl` and to `css` files should be similar. If link to `css` file in html looks like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
```

and Its physical path is

```
public/css/app.css
```

then your `styl` file should be located at

```
stylus/css/app.styl
```

and Express config should be

```js
app.configure('dev', function () {
  ...
  app.use(stylus.middleware({
    src: __dirname + '/stylus/',
    dest: __dirname + '/public/',
    compile: function(str, path) { ... }
  }));
  ...
});
```

What I saw in the [source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/blob/master/lib/middleware.js).

Stylus parses all requests and selects only those that are requested `css` files. Then It combines `css` url's pathname with your `dest` option, replaces `css` with `styl` in pathname and combines result with your `src` option:

```js
// Middleware
return function stylus(req, res, next){
  if ('GET' != req.method && 'HEAD' != req.method) return next();
  var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  if (/\.css$/.test(path)) {
    var cssPath = join(dest, path)
      , stylusPath = join(src, path.replace('.css', '.styl'));

    // ...

  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

Comment: the answer to my problem was not following the exact same path structure in my `styl` folder.  for some reason, i thought that wasn't necessary in express 2.x. thanks!

Comment: `Stylus parses all requests and selects only those that are requested css files`: that's why my `styl` file was not getting processed! I forgot to mention the expected file path of the outputed `css`.